# chmod files with group - error on files with (

Tags: find, quoting, filenames

I have the need to chmod files which are in a certain group. I have come up with this construct:

```
find . -group groupname -exec sh -c 'su -c "chmod -R u+w,g-w,o-w,g+r,o+r ." - groupname {}' \;
```

This works, but fails when the filename has a bracket ( or ) in it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `"{}"` to put double-quotes around the discovered filename.

Comment: your missing the standard find `-name` option.  All you need is `find . -name '*' -group groupname` if in fact you want to capture all files.

Comment: @jnbbender why would you want `-name '*'`? That's a no-op.

Comment: @roaima It was failing for me without it.  Works just fine with it.

Comment: I don't get why you might need two `sh`s.

Comment: @phk - couldn't figure out how to quote the su -c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set `IFS` variable to `$(echo -en "\n\b")` , for example:

```
#!/bin/bash
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
find . -group groupname -exec sh -c 'su -c "chmod -R u+w,g-w,o-w,g+r,o+r ." - groupname {}' \;
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you're using the `{}` interpolation leaves the filename unquoted, so it's a bit like running `chmod u=rw some(filename).txt`, which will fail in the way you've described.

One solution is to move the `{}` out of a quoted string so that `find` can handle it properly itself.

Another problem is that you seem to be splitting the `chmod` command, with part of it inside the `su` and part of it outside. (Demonstrate this by replacing `sh` with `echo`.) The result is a broken command, and I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve.

Try this (remove the `echo` when you're sure it's doing what you want):

```
su -c "
    find . -group groupname -exec echo chmod -R u+w,go+r,go-w {} \;
"
```

Do you really intend to apply a recursive `chmod` to every directory that happens to have group `groupname`? Perhaps you should consider `-type d` in the set of predicates.

Comment: Hi, yes I have since come to the conclusion that this is too slow, so I just use chmod --silent